# need install an iPhone application pre-release

Tags: iphone, release, device

i'm not an iphone programmer, but this is my problem :

i have the source code of an iPhone application in x-code, i need to upload it in a ftp server to allow my client install and test a pre-release, but i need to add his device id some where in the application to be able to install it in his iPhone, i have the device id but i don't know how to add it in the application.

Can anyone help me please, if you have documentation or good links, send them to me please
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use one of the following services:

https://testflightapp.com/

or

http://www.hockeyapp.net/

These make it much easier to register client devices and install pre-release builds.

Comment: can u help me please how to add a device id in one of these sites, I'm lost !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576201/automating-testflightapp-with-xcode-and-provisioning-portal

Comment: you add devices to the provisioning profile in the apple dev portal, no way around that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746988/publishing-to-testflight-new-testers-do-i-really-need-to-rebuild-download-my-p

Answer (score 1):

you have to sign into [Apple Developer Portal](http://developer.apple.com/ios) and add his device id in the appropriate section then you can use [TestFlight](http://testflightapp.com) with a provisioning profile from the portal to let people use it "pre-release"

Comment: i'm signed in but what is the appropriate section to add the device id please?